# ActiveMQ on Windows not enabling JMX

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I am using ActiveMQ 5.16.1 on Windows. I set `useJmx="true"` in the `<broker>` section of `activemq.xml`.  However, after starting ActiveMQ nothing is listening on the default JMX port `1099`, and JConsole does not show ActiveMQ as a target.

I tried explicitly enabling the JMX connector in `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<managementContext>
    <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
</managementContext>
```

However, I get this failure in the ActiveMQ startup console:

```
WARN | Failed to start JMX connector Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is:
            java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind. Will restart management to re-create JMX connector, trying to remedy this issue.
```

This returns an empty result

```
netstat -an | grep 1099
```

Answer (score 1):

JMX is most likely already running via the startup script-- hence the error message. I'm betting the netstat -na is run *after* the ActiveMQ process has given you the error and the process has already exited.

This is a confusing bit-- that setting in managementContext should be createConnector="false" when using the Apache ActiveMQ build.

Background: ActiveMQ is essentially a library, so it has features to support running in all sorts of different ways. When you start ActiveMQ from the Apache build download, the JMX settings are usually started using -D parameters found in the bin/setenv script. The managementContext setting is to instruct ActiveMQ s embedded in a different runtime/build that does *not* start JMX itself.

Comment: I start with the default of createConnector="false" and JMX does not appear to be enabled.  Setting it to createConnector="true" was an attempt to force enablement, which also fails with the new problem of "theport is already is use", which is baffling, because nothing is published on the port.  I gave up and used the jolokia REST API.

Comment: Perhaps a firewall is enabled? Jolokia is a proxy to the JMX Management Service. If Jolokia is working, then the JMX info is being registered correctly.

Comment: Windows firewall is off.  ActiveMQ doesn't appear on jconsole, and nothing is listening on the default port.  Its OK, I am happy with the REST solution,

Comment: To be clear, Jolokia is "REST like" but not strictly REST. See the [Jolokia documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html) for more details.